# Methanol-water mix freezing points - clarify contradictory online data > 60% w/w?

Tags: aqueous-solution, alcohols, phase, melting-point, mixtures

Extending an exploration of windshield washer-fluid choices to freezing points of methanol-water mixes, all web-sources located agreed to within a couple of degrees from 0-60% w/w, yet above this proportion (and below 100%), repeatedly came across conflicting data (which fell into three groups). (Yes, the disagreements are all outside the range of winter driving on this planet - except perhaps for around Vostok Station...)

| w/w | various graphs by eye | various tables | engineering toolbox table | all˚C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60% | - 71 | - 71 | - 71 | ˚C |
| 70% | -102 | -137 | - 82 | ˚C |
| 80% | -116 | -143 | - 87 | ˚C |
| 90% | -108 | -146 | - 90 | ˚C |
| 100% | - 96 | - 98 | - 98 | ˚C |

examples of sources for above data:

http://www.methanol.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/FreezingPointsMethanol-WaterSolutions.pdf    graph
https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2011153147A1/en table (~ 1/3 way into the document)
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/methanol-water-d_987.html        table

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Different source data, different data processing, different errors made.

Comment: Thanks. Your emphasis on "different" inspired a new search strategy which led to a satisfactory answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

From Solid-Liquid Phase Diagram of the System Methanol-Water by G. A. Miller and D. K. Carpenter in J. Chem. Eng. Data 1964, 9, 3, 371–373 (July 1, 1964) [https://doi.org/10.1021/je60022a017]

> "A solution of methanol and water that is methanol-rich tends to form
> a glass when cooled below the melting point. The liquid is very
> viscous at such temperatures (below -100° C.) because of the presence
> of hydrogen-bonded polymers. *Because it is difficult to induce
> crystallization, the melting point is determined from a warming curve.
> Much of the wide divergence of melting point data for the composition
> range of 55 to 95 mole per cent* methanol results from the use of
> cooling curves.*"

* by a back-of-a-napkin calculation (assuming 32.042 g/mol MeOH and 18.015 g/mol H2O) the mole percentage mentioned is approximately 68% to 97% methanol (w/w).

Further - successful - online research was inspired by a comment; it appears the failure to find information with common search terms was due to a language difference. It seems specialists (presumably physical chemists) use "solid-liquid equilibrium" or "solid-liquid phase diagram" in documents which may completely exclude the term "freezing-point" - such as the publication quoted above which answers the original question.